# I want print a receipt with Xprinter XP-58 printer using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing

I am making Kiosk based to React, and I have XP-58 receipt printer.
I need print a receipt when order is accepted.
Receipt printer will connect with USB.

I tried modules like printer, node-thermal-printer. printer failed when installing, second one failed when I tried to run.
After some time, I found receiptio module which could be work, but I am still stuck.

EDIT : This is code i tried with receiptio in Node.js:

```
const receiptio = require("receiptio");

const receiptmd = `^^^RECEIPT

12/18/2021, 11:22:33 AM
Asparagus | 1| 1.00
Broccoli  | 2| 2.00
Carrot    | 3| 3.00
---
^TOTAL | ^6.00`;

receiptio
  .print(receiptmd, "-d 192.168.123.100 -p generic -c 42")
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

I runned this code, after some time, it didn't print and just ended. It just printed disconnect in node.js.

Edit 2 : So I should make a nodejs based web server and receive data with react, but the code is still problem.

Comment: Share piece of code that you tried . So people can easily sort out whats going wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> i runned this code, after some time, it didn't print and just ended.

When I try running that code in a React application, it spits out a **huge** stream of error messages such as:

> Failed to compile.
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in
> '/Users/david/tmp/jdkfjsdkfjdfjdkjfdk/foofdofdofd/node_modules/pngjs/lib'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. 
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you
> need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

`receiptio` depends on APIs that are provided by Node.js and not by browsers.

You can't use it in a React application, because React applications run in browsers.

The closest you could come would be to write a Node.js-based web webservice that uses that module and then send your data to that web service using, e.g., Ajax.

Comment: Though I tested that code at nodejs, now i need find another way to find print receipt at react. I take a look to react-to-print, that wasn't a thing i wanted. Any idea?

Comment: I refer you to the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Understood. First, I am trying to print with nodejs, but after looking receiptio github, I found I should use virtual serial port driver. Can you help with that?